# How to put text on the right side of the table header

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In UITableView we have headers

For example

Say I want to group businesses by the building they are in.

BuildingA 10
Business1
Business2
Business3
Business4

How do I arrange so that the 10 is on the right side of the header

Comment: i am creating the tutorial for that and ASAP i give the resopnse

Comment: wow. You can put the tutorial here.

Comment: Both answer is good. I think I like the second one due to the nib thingy. +1 for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a) to add your own extra label whose rect is somewhere on the right side, like `CGRectMake(280,5,30,20);`.  You should also set it so the text aligns right.

Note that if you do this, you also have to provide the left-side label (since it is no longer there) and you must override [`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForHeaderInSection%3a) as well.

Comment: Well +1 for you. But the other answer is good too. I think both are good but I can only choose one :)

Comment: To be fair, in his code, he's only loading one UILabel and adding it, which doesn't do what you had asked for.  Also, he sets the height of the header to `2`, which would render any text unreadable.

Comment: UIView *v=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tHeader" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [(UILabel*)[v viewWithTag:1] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",section+1]];
 I'll use something like that too. You use CGRectMake, which may be more effective. I'll see what I'll use eventually. But I like the idea that all views should be done in nib.

Comment: It just seems so iffy to have code which depends on `objectAtIndex:constant`... it just seems not very future-proof, as in you might change your nib in the future (say add an object behind them) and then have to hunt down all the places where you referenced the nib - it seems like a very non-Apple way to do things.

Comment: Actually, since the view is the root element of the nib and it's just the table header in that nib, it's not that bad, but his `heightForHeaderInSection:` method is still iffy (grr, constants)

Comment: Make sense. The I do not like tag either. I like the view to be subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

In that u can use the custom header cell then that cell attach in the header.

for that following code is implement.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 5;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 2;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *v=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tHeader" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [(UILabel*)[v viewWithTag:1] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",section+1]];
    return v;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (section==0)?5:((section==1)?7:((section==2)?3:4));
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"       Hello-%i",indexPath.row];

    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}
```

[download source from here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/custom%20header%20cell/SectionedTableDemo.zip/download)

Comment: What about if I do not want v viewWithTag:1, what about if I want the view returned to be a subclass of uiview, how to do so?